# Setting reply-to as bcc

Tags: python, email, mime

I am using python mime and I would like to implement that the receiver of the mail replies to two different mail addresses, if he clicks the "reply to" button in his mail client.

```
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = my_subj
msg.attach(MIMEText(my_msg, 'plain'))
msg.add_header('reply-to', reply_to)
msg.add_header('Bcc', reply_to_as_bcc)
```

However the reply_to_as_bcc address just receives a copy of the mail I am originally sending. How to implement that the reply_to_as_bcc address is occurring in the bcc field, if the user owning the receiver_email account is clicking reply to?

Comment: Just to clarify, `bcc` is a blind copy. Meaning that person will get a copy "as is" of the original email without being adressed directly. It's like printing the email in a printer and giving that user the hard copy. The email contents will be exactly as if it was sent to `msg['To']` and there for I don't think what you're after will work. Might be if the client does some trickery to interpret and try to send it as another user, but that will fail else where in the chain sadly.

Comment: Exactly, the reply_to_as_bcc gets the same mail like the receiver_email address. My intention is that the reply_to_as_bcc gets a bcc of the mail that the receiver mail is sending, tho. I used to implement it by declaring msg.add_header('reply-to', reply_to + ", " + reply_to_as_bcc ). But the reply_to address should not see the reply_to_as_bcc address, because it's an internal mail account.

Comment: Well, again, BCC is a one way street. If you want it to be secret, each sender has to manually declare that he or she want's to send a "secret copy" to a colleague. If the email was known in the e-mail chain, it's by definition not secret anymore. There for, I don't think you can achieve what you're trying to achieve. Not without giving away the e-mail at least in a hidden header or something that the user **usually** don't see.